# node js exclude / outsource code snippets in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes

i have to routes in node js with nearly the same code. I want to exclude this code in a function, but when i call the function the process (route) don't wait for the return var of the new function. Maybe someone can create an example for me, how i can handle that. I think is something like callback and promise.

Best,

Simon

a pseudo example with express.

```
function getUser(variable) {
   return variable;
}

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.json(getUser(a));
});

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.json(getUser(b));
});
```

Comment: Post your code here to get better idea.

Comment: hope this example help

Comment: it doesn't. provide more of what getUser does. It may also help to include the original version.

Comment: so as my question understanding, you wanted to wait for an output until your function does resolve an output. right or wrong? please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: yeah you are right. i want to wait for the function output and after that the res.json must be called.

Comment: @user3807340 please check an answer I have posted and let me know whether it will understandable or not to you  and will it helpful to resolve you issue or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use promise to prevent further execution until a process complete.

For the demo purpose here I use setTimeout to hold a process, so route must wait minimum 5000ms to resolve the promise. Once the promise has been resolved, we shall get the value in then and finally with res.json return the response to the client.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000; //lets the port be set by Hero

app.use(bodyParser.json());

function getUser(variable) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(variable);
        }, 5000);
    });
}
app.get('/user', function (req, res) {
    getUser("user-data").then((data) => {
        res.status(200).json({data: data});
    });
});

app.get('/info', function (req, res) {
    getUser("info-data").then((data) => {
        res.status(200).json({data: data});
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Comment: oh thanks. looks good. the setTimeOut is only to demonstrate the ".then" right?

Comment: yes because otherwise It's not possible to explain the logic

Comment: it Workshop. Thanks